# Is microsoft sql server 2008 enterprise and developer edition totaly same?

Tags: sql-server

What would happen if you use SQL server developer edition on real server ?

It says that it is fully same as enterprise edition. Are'nt there any difference at real ?

I mean for example you installed developer edition and enterprise edition on equal machines. Would they show same performance on product environment ?

Comment: and is Evaluation: Trial  same as fully licenced software ? at microsoft sql server 2008 enterprise edition ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance - yes. The license for Developer Edition precludes you from using it in a production environment however. If you get tagged for an audit, you're up a certain creek without a paddle.

I'm going to quote myself in a reply to someone else recently, because this is relevant here as well:

> Bit of advice : your questions show a
>   lot of "beginner" traits. That's not a
>   bad thing, and I'm not trying to
>   discourage you from asking questions
>   here. However, you might do well to
>   find a qualified or experienced
>   person, either physically near you, or
>   online, that you could engage in a
>   real dialog about what you need for
>   this project. This site is
>   specifically for targeted questions
>   and answers, and I think you would
>   benefit a lot more from an "overview"
>   type of conversation instead.

In your specific case, you may want to hire a consultant, because this sounds like a potentially commercial operation and you may need a professional to help you. Try to structure the engagement as a knowledge transfer, so you can get to that level someday yourself.

Comment: thanks for answer. i also wonder this : Evaluation: Trial same as fully licenced software ? at microsoft sql server 2008 enterprise edition ? because it gives 180 day trial which is sufficient to format computer once at 6 months i guess

Comment: Do not ask questions about how to circumvent licensing restrictions on this site. Anyway, it will still bite you in the ass if you get audited. Read the edits to my answer above.

Comment: ok i understand you. but i just want to learn that which edition is this : Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Evaluation : Trial Experience for IT Professionals

Comment: and also are there any difference between trial and fully licenced software . ofc asking about microsoft sql server 2008 R2 :)

Comment: Read the documentation for what you have.

Comment: it seems like you are consultant i see :) well no problem.

Comment: No, I'm not a consultant

Comment: I have to agree with mfinni here licensing is nothing to joke around with. The Trial / Evals are just that they are ment for IT pros to have a chance to setup a test lab to determin if it will meet thier needs. EVALUATION LICENSING CAN NOT BE USED IN PRODUCTION! just don't even think about it.

Answer (score 3):

For SQL Server 2005 and 2008: yes. 'Developer' edition, as well as 'Evaluation' editions are just licensing restricted versions of Enterprise Edition.

For SQL Server 2008 R2: **No**. The 'Developer' and 'Evaluation' versions are licensing restricted versions of the **Data Center** Edition, not Enterprise Edition. The main difference between DC and EE is that DE edition can scale above 64 CPU cores.

Evalutation and Developer editions **cannot** be used in production: doing so is a violation of the license you agreed to when you installed the product.

Comment: "For SQL Server 2008 R2: No. The 'Developer' and 'Evaluation' versions are licensing restricted versions of the Data Center Edition". Interesting. Do you have a reference/link for this?

Answer (score 0):

Developer edition has the exact same features as Enterprise edition. The only difference is the licensing. You can't use Developer in Production